# align text center_vertical in editText not appearing precisely

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-edittext

I've got a layout file containing following code:

```
 <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/edittextgreen" />
```

The background file looks like this:

```
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        <solid 
            android:color="@color/Black" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/Green" />

        <corners
            android:radius="100dp" />
    </shape>
```

Now that's what appears:
[image]

As you can probably see, the text is not perfectly aligned to the vertical center of the edittext view. How do I align it properly? I mean, I already added the

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

But it still looks like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_bg"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="50" />
```

I am using this and your background xml and it is coming perfectly in center.

Are you doing something through code ? Please don't mind the listview below it
[image]

Comment: Just some code to change the EditText text dependent on a seekBar, but that shouldn't be the problem... However, thanks for the response!

Comment: I don't know what you are doing in code by the above code works with only xml

Comment: Found my issue, had another style applied to this xml file which had an padding_bottom attribute... sorry for that! thanks for your help

Comment: i guessed that would be it. next time paste full xml